# How to parse nested JSON data using Codable protocol with custom names

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

After reading many sources unable to get it there are two issues one : nested data, second name of one property is "Type" which is not accepted by swift saying conflict with .... can someone sort this out or explain straight proper way here is the json response

```
"IsSuccess": true,
"Message": "Data Returned",
"ResponseData": [
    {
        "PackageId": 1025,
        "PackageName": "Progesterone",
        "Price": 00.0,
        "DiscountedPrice": 1.0,
        "Type": "Test",
        "TestPackageGroupId": 3,
        "SampleTypeList": [
            {
                "TestSampleTypeId": "50",
                "SampleName": "Serum",
                "ColourCode": "#FFB500"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "PackageId": 1916,
        "PackageName": "24 hour Albumin creatinine ratio (ACR)",
        "Price": 00.0,
        "DiscountedPrice": 1.0,
        "Type": "Test",
        "TestPackageGroupId": 3,
        "SampleTypeList": [
            {
                "TestSampleTypeId": "66",
                "SampleName": "24 hrs Urine",
                "ColourCode": "#212DC1"
            }
        ]
    },
```

how to write data class for above the property "Type" is unaccepted if I use it as it is

```
   struct PriceListAll : Codable
        {
          let Message: String
          let IsSuccess: Bool
          let ResponseData: [ResponseData]
         }


     struct ResponseData:Codable
        {

                let PackageId: Int
                let PackageName: String
                let Price: Double
                let DiscountedPrice: Double
                let Type: String
                let TestPackageGroupId: Int
                let SampleTypeList: [SampleTypeList]
             }


      struct SampleTypeList:Codable
          {
             let TestSampleTypeId: Int
             let SampleName: String
             let ColourCode: String

         }
```

Error : Type member must not be named 'Type', since it would conflict with the 'foo.Type' expression

Answer (score 0):

Name of the `Type` is a reserved word in swift thats why you are getting `Error : Type member must not be named 'Type', since it would conflict with the 'foo.Type' expression`  this error message  . If your model represent a key  with name `Type` , you must use it like

> ```
> let `Type`: String
> ```

Comment: error is gone so it will work? I mean data will be fetched correctly

Comment: The answer is the error message says what I wrote as an answer above. Yes if your service and decoding is ok , it must work

Answer (score 0):

You can name properties whatever you like, just add coding keys, so decoder knows where to find it.

```swift
struct ResponseData: Codable {
    let PackageId: Int
    let PackageName: String
    let Price: Double
    let DiscountedPrice: Double
    let MyCustomTypeName: String
    let TestPackageGroupId: Int
    let SampleTypeList: [SampleTypeList]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case PackageId
        case PackageName
        case Price
        case DiscountedPrice
        case MyCustomTypeName = "Type"
        case TestPackageGroupId
        case SampleTypeList
    }
}
```

Comment: Type 'ResponseData' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' is the error when using enum Codingkeys

Comment: My bad, all cases should be mentioned, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename Type as responseType and add enum CodingKeys for decoding.

```
struct ResponseData: Codable {

    let responseType: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case responseType = "Type"
    }
}
```

Comment: Type 'ResponseData' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable' is the error when using enum Codingkeys